# How can I find out what package or packages a particular repo is for in my sources when I forget?

Tags: command-line, repository

Is there a command to discover what a particular repo updates? I like to clean out my sources of unused repos often, and sometimes forget what a particular repo is there for. I just Google it when this happens, but was curious if there's a terminal command that would tell me?

Answer (score 4):

You have several console options here:

- For known package name you can use `apt-cache policy package-name` - see example below from my system:

  > ```
  > $ apt-cache policy doublecmd-gtk 
  > doublecmd-gtk:
  >   Installed: 0.9.7-0+svn9235~testing
  >   Candidate: 0.9.7-0+svn9235~testing
  >   Version table:
  >  *** 0.9.7-0+svn9235~testing 500
  >         500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_16.04  Packages
  >         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  >      0.7.1-2 500
  >         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
  > ```

  It means that I have `doublecmd-gtk` package installed from third-party repository on OpenSuSe BuildService. You can find its `sources.list` file with command like:

  > `$ grep -r "http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_16.04" /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`
  >   `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Alexx2000.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_16.04/ /`
- If you know PPA name, then you can ask `aptitude` about package origin with command like `aptitude search "?origin(LP-PPA-alexlarsson)"` - it will show the same package names as in Synaptic output.

Also you can try one of GUI tools:

- Install Synaptic Package Manager with `sudo apt-get install synaptic apt-xapian-index` and use Origin tab here - see example from my system:

  > [image: Synaptic Package Manager, origin tab]

  From the screenshot above you can see that I have added Alex Larsson's FlatPak PPA and I have one package installed from it.
- You can use special user-friendly application named Y PPA Manager. You can install it with

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
  ```

  Then you have to click on *Manage PPAs* button and then select line of needed PPA and list its packages with *List Packages* button and you will get something like shown on the screenshot below:

  > [image: Y PPA Manager, Manage PPAs, List Packages]

You can combine methods above to get the best result. I use many of them depending on the circumstances.